# Select from table, then insert that (value + 1) into another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, insert, dataset

Thanks for viewing my question. Hopefully I can get an answer. I have a project in C#. I am trying to grab an IF field from a table. Once I have that data, I want to increment the value by 1. (For example, I grab 10000, and add 1 which makes it 10001.) Then, I want to input the incremented value into another table.

This is what I have so far (only the select query):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select reqID from [RequestID] where (ID = 1)", con);
```

I have tried using DataSet without any progress. I'm not too familiar with coding, but trying!

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
myDA1.Fill(ds, "RequestID");
Int64 RequestID = default(Int64);
RequestID = ds.Table("RequestID").Rows(0).Item("ReqID");
RequestID += 1;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Josh

Comment: I used ExecuteScalar, and it worked perfectly!                         Int64 RequestID = default(Int64);
ReqID = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
ReqID += 1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run:

```
INSERT INTO yourOtherTable ( reqId ) 
SELECT reqID + 1 
FROM RequestID
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran that query, but I'm not getting the value into the other table. This is what I did:                            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [Transactions] (ReqID) select ReqID+1 from [RequestID]", con);

Comment: I also added a WHERE clause in there with no change.

Comment: Well, you have to execute it. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the value from a table in SQL?

If so you probably don't need to play around with Datasets, you just need to read the value from SQL.

[MSDN article on Ado.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx#_SqlClient)

Once you get your value using SqlDataReader you can increment it and reinsert it.

[Simple CRUD operations using Ado.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1155/Simple-ADO-NET-Database-Read-Insert-Update-and-Del)

Comment: Datasets are notoriously nasty, I think if you concentrate on reading the value out, you're halfway there as it's just a small case of incrementing it before reinserting.

Comment: I figured it out. I used ExecuteScalar.                                        Int64 RequestID = default(Int64);
            ReqID = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            RequestID += 1;

Answer (score 0):

Just change in this

sample

```
string sql1 = string.Format(@"select reqID from [RequestID] where (ID = 1)");
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, con);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        con.Open();
        da1.Fill(ds1);
        RequestID = ds.Table[0]["RequestID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just increment the value in SQL? It is really good at this sort of thing. With your desired result, you could do something like this.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select reqID + 1 as reqID from [RequestID] where (ID = 1)", con);
con.Open();
List<int> requestIds = new List<int>();
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
  while(reader.Read()){
    requestIds.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
  } 
}
return requestIds;  // I find that Lists are much easier to work with 
// than DataTables, particularly for novices.
```

if you want something more explicit, the line

```
    requestIds.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
```

could be modified into:

```
    requestIds.Add(reader.GetInt32(0) + 1);
```

with you leaving the query the same.

Edit: Modified response due to the comment:

> Thanks for the reply. I am wanting to input that value into another table, but I will be adding the value "later", with all the other data that will be entered by the end user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am wanting to input that value into another table, but I will be adding the value "later", with all the other data that will be entered by the end user.